# Is this a real 400 year old (brass or bronze ) coin?

Tags: identification

**what the seller told me about this coin:**

It’s a 400 year old coin, it was found in Pakistan and he said some thing like mintmultani (may be it’s a language or name of a place), students from China come here (Multan, Pakistan) to buy these coins

**dimensions:**

diameter = 2 cm

thickness= 0.7 cm
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to HSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: This isn't a valuation site so best to change the main focus of your question to details of historical interest (e.g. where issued, value in its time period....).

Comment: 400 years old?  From the 1600's?  I'm skeptical.

Comment: Search for [copper coins from the Mughal era](https://en.numista.com/catalogue/inde_moghol-1.html) to see similar objects.(Yes [400 years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mughal_Empire) ago). The [Dam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dam_(Indian_coin)) was one type from this time frame and region..

Comment: The 'mintmultani' is likely a reference to the fact that during the reign of [Akbar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akbar),(from 1542 to 1605) the [Multan district](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multan) had both [a silver and a copper mint](https://books.google.com/books?id=hXkluRg7xG0C&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&dq=multan%20mint&pg=PA47#v=onepage&q=multan%20mint&f=false), so a copper coin from this area at this time is historically quite appropriate.